# Using a register in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded

I'm trying to setup a structure that will contain a register, pin number, and adc value. I want to change the value of the register using a function called setLEDs. However, I am getting errors saying

```
expression must have integral type
expression must have pointer type
```

Here is my struct. The LED_X and ports are defined above.

```
typedef struct
{
    const uint32_t pin;
    volatile uint32_t * const reg;
    uint32_t adcValue;
} LED_LUT;

#define LED_LUT_DEF {{LED_0, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R, 0}, \
                     {LED_1, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R, 0}, \
                     {LED_2, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R, 0}, \
                     {LED_3, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTC_DATA_R, 0}, \
                     {LED_4, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R, 0}, \
                     {LED_5, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R, 0}, \
                     {LED_6, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R, 0}, \
                     {LED_7, (volatile uint32_t*)GPIO_PORTF_DATA_R, 0},}
```

and here is the function that receives the compile errors:

```
void setLEDs(LED_LUT ledLUT[NUM_OF_LEDS])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < NUM_OF_LEDS; ++i)
    {
        //If above threshold, set the pin, else clear it
        if (ledLUT[i].adcValue > ADC_THRESHOLD)
        {
            ledLUT[i]->reg |= (uint32_t*)ledLUT[i].pin;//error here
        }
        else
        {
            ledLUT[i]->reg &= (uint32_t*)~ledLUT[i].pin;//error here
        }

    }
}
```

The ledLUT is initialized in main as:

```
LED_LUT ledLUT[8] = LED_LUT_DEF;
```

I think it is probably just a syntax error but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried many different combinations of type casting/dereferencing but have not found the correct solution.

Comment: assuming that the strings like LED0 are previously defined: this kind of line: ledLUT[i]->reg |= (uint32_t*)ledLUT[i].pin; should be written: *(ledLUT[i]->reg) |= (uint32_t*)ledLUT[i].pin;  however, it is better to keep an image of the register in memory, update the image, then write the whole image at each update.  Because writing single pins creates a read/update/write cycle that often will not work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ledLUT[i]->reg |= (uint32_t*)ledLUT[i].pin
```

Should be

```
*(ledLUT[i].reg) |= (uint32_t)ledLUT[i].pin
```

And

```
ledLUT[i]->reg &= (uint32_t*)~ledLUT[i].pin
```

Should be

```
*(ledLUT[i].reg) &= (uint32_t)~ledLUT[i].pin
```

Because ledLUT is an array of structs, not an array of pointers.

Comment: Half right - you still need to dereference the pointer that is contained *within* the struct, in order to perform the chosen logical operation on the contents of the memory-mapped special function register it points to.

Comment: And the pin member is not a pointer but rather a value (op's mistake)